# Include jars without mentioning it as dependency in pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, pom.xml

I have a maven project and there are about 20 jar files that need to be included in that project. Is there any way to include all those jar files without mentioning each of them as a dependency in pom?

Comment: Could you clarify where do you want to `include` these 20 jars?

Comment: Do you want to package them into a war or ear? What is your aim? If they are dependencies, you should add them as dependencies.

Comment: @michaldo I want to reference them in the project and build a new jar.I want to create a jar with some code that reference the other jars. My aim to skip adding 20 dependencies individually.

Comment: @JFMeier .I want to create a jar with some code that reference the other 20 jars. My aim to skip adding 20 dependencies individually.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is essential that you list each dependency in the pom. It may cost you 5 minutes, but it is worth it. The dependencies should be drawn from a repository, e.g. MavenCentral or your company Nexus/Artifactory, not just from the file system. In this way you get a reproducible build that works on other machines as well.